# Want to print output of two background shell functions sequentially

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, printing

I have two functions in my shell scripts I run in background:

```
function foo {
  # do a bunch of things
  # print a lot of output
}

function bar {
  # do more things
  # print out more things
}

foo &
bar &
wait
```

The output is printed out as it comes out to stdout or stderr, so there's a lot of overlap:

```
[foo] output line 1
[bar] output line 1 
[foo] output line 2
[bar] output line 2
```

I'd like the output to be printed out sequentially (all of `foo`'s output followed by all of `bar`'s output) so that it's easier to read. Do I need to write the output to a file, then print out the file, or is there a way to do this without writing to files?

Comment: Why do you run them in the background if you then wait for them? If you need their output sorted, is it crucial that they run simultaneously?

Comment: I'm doing this in order to save time. Each function takes about a minute to run, but they don't depend on each other.

Comment: @DDay They may not depend on each other, but in your description their outputs do depend on each other sequentially. So instead of hacky tricks, just do everything without backgrounding. Or make one function call the other.

Answer (score 4):

Every output is written to a file anyway, I don’t know of a way *not* to use files. I’d use tempfiles as needed, e.g.:

```
$ a=$(mktemp)
$ b=$(mktemp)
$ echo 1 >$a & echo 2 >$b & wait
$ cat $b
2
$ cat $a
1
```

`mktemp` creates two tempfiles `a` and `b`, the `echo` commands write to the tempfiles, you can then use `cat` to print from them at any time you need the output. If you want to redirect both stdout and stderr, use `&>` instead.

Comment: @PerlDuck correct, I mixed up two things there

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I didn’t manage to use fd’s here, do you know a way? However, it’s not much of a difference to tempfiles created by `mktemp`…

Comment: This https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122101/251553 looks scary but might be adapted to the problem at hand. ;-) I haven't tried, though.

Comment: @perlduck  The `$(...)` is implemented with anonymous temp files as well, so not much difference to what dessert is doing which is much more explicit and clear, IMHO.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy No I didn’t, I had `>3` instead of `>&3` there – which wouldn’t work without opening it first with e.g. `exec 3<> $(mktemp)`. And aren’t fd’s removed when the process exits? Needless to say that doesn’t help here either… Yup, tempfiles it is, plain and simple. :)

Comment: @dessert Ah, yes, sorry, misread that one.  Although to be fair internally bash still opens those files as fd's. PotEHto potAHto :)

Comment: You only need to redirect the second command's output. The first one might print directly to the terminal. :)

Comment: @egmont Of course, I did it this way just for the “print at any time you need” part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the system is writing to files anyway to accomplish this; they're just temp files.  However, you could have the `foo` process output to one file  and rename it when complete. Have `bar` watch for the rename of said file, and when `foo` completes the rename, bar outputs the `foo` output then prints its own output, a la:

```
function foo {  
  # do a bunch of things  
  # print a lot of output to /tmp/foo.work  
  # mv /tmp/foo.work /tmp/foo.done  
}  

function bar {   
  # do more things  
  # write more things to /tmp/bar.done  
  # if exist /tmp/foo.done print /tmp/foo.done else wait 1 and recheck  
  # rm /tmp/foo.done  
  # print /tmp/bar.done  
}
```